# Entity framework loads all records for large table when only a subset is required

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table that lists all errors and warnings for an device (a hardware device whose details we store in the db).  That is covered by a single `DeviceLog`.

The `DeviceLog` table stores both current and archive errors, this means though that for devices with a large archive it is very slow to get out the current error / warning state.

```
device.Errors = databaseDevice.Errors.Where(
    e => e.Current && 
    e.LogEntryType == Models.DeviceLogEntryType.Error)
        .Select(e => new DeviceErrorLog()).ToList();
```

So the in this current case there are about 5000 entries in `DeviceLog` for this specific device, but no current ones so `device.Errors.Count() == 0` but if, in intellisense, I hover over `databaseDevice.Errors` it shows the actual full count.

Is this behaviour expected, if so then how can I make this faster as I thought this should be a fast operation especially as I am specifying a very direct and easily searchable subset of the data

To clarify the data structure:

```
public class DeviceLogEntry
{        
    public DeviceLogEntryType /* An Enum */ LogEntryType { get; set; }
    public bool Current { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @OndrejJanacek `e.Current` has to be a `bool`. @Chris, when you hover over `databaseDevice.Errors` in Visual Studio, it enumerates it - this doesn't actually happen at runtime.

Comment: `I hover over databaseDevice.Errors` - Hovering over an `IEnumerable` might execute it forcing it to load the entire records. Once loaded, the records are cached.

Comment: I thought as much, thanks for clarifying though.  Any ideas on how to make this process faster as it still takes about 1 seconds to complete?

Comment: @Chris Depending on the number of options in the `enum`, you could put an index on the log entry type. Alternatively, if there is only one single `Current` record, consider moving it to it's own table so it doesn't need to be queried

Comment: With the current code, it looks like correct sql is generated which load only requested records. So if that is still slower, try optimizing on the db server with appropriate indexes on the fields involved. Code is fine.

Comment: @Mathew That cannot be done solely through EF can it?

Comment: Not aware of any direct api, you can call sql for creating indexes using with a custom database initializer.

Comment: @Mathew hovering over an `IEnumerable` most certainly will not execute it (and cached where?). Hovering over an object with a `Count` property might execute that property, but there's no reason that would involve actually tallying all items.

Comment: @JonHanna Aah.. yes, you'll need to click the results button to execute it, But `Context` object certainly caches loaded entities as far as I know, but not sure if executing via debugger and direct code makes any difference in that case.

Comment: Thats true, it shows me the full count BEFORE I click the Refresh / Enumeration button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but if, in intellisense, I hover over databaseDevice.Errors it shows the actual full count

Why shouldn't it? If you are hovering over `databaseDevice.Errors`, then intellisense is going to try to get you useful information about `databaseDevice.Errors`, of which the Count (produced by calling `select count(*) from errors`) is an example of such.

It is `device.Errors` that includes the `Where` constraint, not `databaseDevice.Errors`.

> if so then how can I make this faster as I thought this should be a fast operation

Passing `select count(*)` should be a fast operation. But that's also irrelevant to your code, since your code isn't that which you have run by intellisense in this case; your code is:

```
databaseDevice.Errors.Where(
    e => e.Current && 
    e.LogEntryType == Models.DeviceLogEntryType.Error)
        .Select(e => new DeviceErrorLog()).ToList()
```

Which will execute something like:

```
select * from errors where e.current = 1 and e.LogType = 52
```

(Or whatever integer that enum value corresponds to).

And then building a list from it. It doesn't matter what intellisense did in a case that doesn't correspond to the actual executed code.

Two things you can do to improve performance though:

1. Check the indices on the database table, as being able to quickly lookup on `current` and `logEntryType` will affect how fast the underlying SQL executes.
2. Drop the `ToList()` unless you'll be dealing with those results more than once. If you will be dealing with it more than once, then that's great; get it into memory and hit it repeatedly as needed. If you'll not be dealing with it more than once, or if those ways you deal with it will involve further `Where`, then don't waste time building a list, just to go and query that list again, when you could just query the results themselves.

Comment: Hi Jon. Good answer thanks.  I think you are right in your assumption of what the SQL would be. I added indexes on both columns but it made it no faster.  I require `ToList()` as I return this result to a WCF web service.  I'm still lost on why this is so slow though :/

Comment: @Chris one thing I find very useful is to run SQL Server Profiler in tandem with debugging. That way one can see the SQL generated and run, which can catch both cases where the SQL is poor-quality (the SQL from EF and the other Linq-based ORMs tends to be very good, but there can be some cases where an N+1 approach is all it can do with the code in question, and one should refactor), or if the SQL Server itself has a problem (if a good-seeming query is slow, try Database Engine Tuning Advisor, though examine the suggestions rather than applying blindly).

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of Entity Framework the behaviour described above us as expected. The context `databaseDevice.Errors` knows how many records there are in the table, however, due to lazy loading the actual results are not fetched until the .ToList() is executed. The full table is not fetched from the database.

I would not expect any performance issues with this but, if there are, adding some indexes to the table should fix that.